# Intersection on big amount of data without BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata, intersection

I have a table (in google BigQuery) showing url visited by people. People are represented by a 10 char id.

If a user visited an url once, there will be 1 line in the table. 
There are around 90M unique people (ids) and around 400K unique domain.

My goal is to get for each domain, the number of unique people who visited it. Result will be shown in an interface
where a user will be able to choose or not a domain and to see the total amount of people selected ( so the sum of unique ids who
visited the domains he chose ).

The thing is, some people may have visited multiple domains. So the total sum will be wrong. 
I have a version where I just get the number of unique ids that visited a domain for each domain, and then in the interface I just add to the total
when a website is selected and I remove from the total when a domain is not choosen. Of course, this doesn't solve the problem
of ids being counting twice.

The big amount of domains makes it impossible to just calculate every intersection possible. 
Also I want to query BigQuery only once for speed and cost reasons. 
I feel like there is no real solution without using BigQuery after each selection, can anyone tell me if i missed something ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `ROLLUP` functionality in `GROUP BY`: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group-by-clause

Example:

```sql
WITH Sales AS (
  SELECT  1 AS day, 'abc' AS user UNION ALL
  SELECT  1, 'abc' UNION ALL
  SELECT  1, 'def' UNION ALL
  SELECT  2, 'abc' UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 'abc' UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 'def' UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 'abc'
)
SELECT
  day,
  COUNT(distinct user) AS total
FROM Sales
GROUP BY ROLLUP(day);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer ! I think your query is supposed to help me query volume for each domain from BigQuery right ?
The problem here is not really to query from BigQuery, but what should I query from BigQuery that would be small enough to allow me to 
do the thing I want to do (displaying the new total volume with no duplication when a domain is added/removed from the selection on the interface)
if I were to manipulate, let's say in Python ? Could you tell me what output you would expect with your query please ? May be I misunderstood.

Comment: The `rollup` allows to query for distinct totals in and over groups. So you don't need workarounds. Try it out and take a closer look at the documentation - I think it solves your problem.